# C# Converting ListBox to String then Aggregate

Tags: c#

I have a listbox being populated from a combo box.  What i need to do is string all the contents of the listbox together and then Aggregate it.

```
string cols = listbox1.items.Aggregate((f, s) => f.value + "," + s.value);
```

doesnt work.

Comment: This is another question you have asked, I have answered, and you have not accepted any of the answers. Why don't you accept something? Is there some problem with all of the given answers? If so, what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items is an ObjectCollection, so all you know for sure is that it contains objects. You can call ToString on any object:

```
        string[] items = listBox1.Items
            .OfType<object>()
            .Select(item => item.ToString())
            .ToArray();
        string result = string.Join(",", items);
```

Note that this is both more readable and more efficient than using aggregate, which causes multiple string concatenations.

Answer (score 3):

pretty old thread, but here's my solution if anybody need it still

```
string cols = string.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<String>());
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that you have strings in the listbox, try this:

```
string cols =
    String.Join(",", listbox1.Items
        .OfType<Object>()
        .Select(i => i.ToString())
        .ToArray());
```

Generally **[String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)** is used to join a string. This is faster than using a StringBuilder as the size of the new string is already known and it doesn't have to copy everything twice.

Comment: `listbox1.Items` is an `Enumerable` not an `Enumerable<T>`

Comment: The Listbox is being populated by a combobox that got all it's information from a SQL table query

Answer (score 0):

```
string cols = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Aggregate((f, s) => f + "," + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to explicitly do ToString()

```
string cols = listbox1.items.Aggregate((f, s) => f.value.ToString() + "," + s.value.ToString());
```