# C# need to convert column with date

Tags: c#

I have a delimited text file:  one of the columns is DocDate

The ddate column looks like this

20070222
20070221

(there is 100's of dates in this text file like this)

so it's (delimited with |)

|DDate|
|20070222|
|20070221|

I need to translate this to
|DDate|
|02/22/2007|
|02/21/2007|

i have a current replace statement that i have this text file being formated in.  If someone could show me how to actually to place that inside of the statement that would be awesome.

```
                using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\nPrep\" + textBox1.Text + "\\CI\\ncr.txt", FileMode.Open)))
                {
                    string fileText = stream.ReadToEnd();

                    fileText = fileText.Replace(@"BegAtt|EndAtt", "BegAtt#|EndAtt#");
                    fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Cc|*RFP", "CC|RFP");
                    fileText = fileText.Replace(@"<swme> ", string.Empty);
                    fileText = fileText.Replace(@" </swme>",";");

                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"C:\" + textBox1.Text + "\\nc" + "\\Data\\ncr.txt", FileMode.Create)))
                    {
                        writer.Write(fileText);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Example:
Before date conversion:
216442|216443|||20080823|EM

After Date:
216442|216443|||08/23/2005|EM

Comment: I forgot to mention that this a delimited file with multiple delimiters

Comment: Does the date always appear in the 5th column? If I see a pipe, 8 digits, then another pipe can I be sure it is a date?

Comment: In this case yes, it will always appear in the 5th column.  But I would love to have the flexabilit yto move it to all other column settings

Comment: How is it possible to know when one table ends and a new table starts? Is there a delimiter between tables?

Comment: Does my answer work for you? If not, please post an example input file and what you want as the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string inputFilename = "input.txt";
        string outputFilename = "output.txt";

        string[] dateColumnNames = { "DDate" };

        using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(inputFilename, FileMode.Open)))
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(outputFilename, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            int[] dateColumns = new int[0];

            while (true)
            {
                string line = stream.ReadLine();
                if (line == null)
                    break;

                // Split into columns.
                string[] columns = line.Split('|');

                // Find date columns.
                int[] newDateColumns =
                    columns.Select((name, index) => new { Name = name, Index = index })
                    .Where(x => dateColumnNames.Contains(x.Name))
                    .Select(x => x.Index)
                    .ToArray();

                if (newDateColumns.Length > 0)
                    dateColumns = newDateColumns;

                // Replace dates.
                foreach (int i in dateColumns)
                {
                    if (columns.Length > i)
                    {
                        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})");
                        columns[i] = regex.Replace(columns[i], "$2/$3/$1");
                        line = string.Join("|", columns);
                    }
                }

                // Make other replacements.
                line = line.Replace(@"BegAtt|EndAtt", "BegAtt#|EndAtt#");
                line = line.Replace(@"Cc|*RFP", "CC|RFP");
                line = line.Replace(@"<swme> ", string.Empty);
                line = line.Replace(@" </swme>", ";");

                // Output line.
                writer.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example input:

```
a|b|c|d|DDate|e
216442|20011223|||20080823|EM 
216443|20011223|||20080824|EM 
a|DDate|c|d|e|f
216442|20011223|||20080823|EM 

<swme> Just a test </swme>
```

Output:

```
a|b|c|d|DDate|e
216442|20011223|||08/23/2008|EM 
216443|20011223|||08/24/2008|EM 
a|DDate|c|d|e|f
216442|12/23/2001|||20080823|EM 

Just a test;
```

Notice that the DDate column changes. You can also specify multiple date columns if you wish. Just change the array `dateColumnNames`.

Comment: Almost. for some strange reason it delimites the wrong thing: input: 386131|386134|386131|386149|20070222 output: 386131|386134|86/13/07531|86/14/07539|20070222 20070222 is the date column

i think is see where i messed in explain:  I want the date column to stay in the same column it cant move because it's a delimited file with a header.  What i ment is if the row changes in the input file the code will adjust for it and write it to same column....

So if date is in column 4, it writes out everything the same just translates column 4 and everything else stays the same

Comment: I've tested it on exactly that line you posted, and it gives the right result. Can you post your header?

Comment: Did you make modifications to the program before testing it? You shouldn't need to hard code the column number - it autodetects it from the column name.

Comment: Header ROW:  
Beg, End, Att#, Att2#, Ddate, Dtype, Dtitle, Creater, Recieved, Sent, Register

Comment: The header row is comma separated?!

Comment: No i'm very sorry it's not.  It's |

Comment: Heres an example output when it gets to writer.WriteLine(line);  

line = "R067967307|R067967310|R67/30/06797|R67/31/06790|20070221|EM;|Fw: manuscript"

Comment: This would be the output I would expect if you wrote string[] dateColumnNames = { "Att" }; instead of string[] dateColumnNames = { "DDate" }; Is that why it is failing?

Comment: No i've absolutely made sure string[] dateColumnNames = { "DDate" };

But it will skip columns, in the instance i showed you its column 3 that got wierd.  Couple lines down it's column 6...

Comment: ID10T error.  Your right this code is fine.  TYVM!!
I was missing [] by the string[] dateColumnNames = { "DDate" };

Comment: Great! It took a long time, but glad it works now. There's also another question you posted 3 days ago that I answered but you never accepted an answer. Did you find a solution to that one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867592/c-converting-listbox-to-string-then-aggregate

Comment: yep :).  Sorry forgot about that 1, I’m going to ask another question here soon.  Lol, I’m so damn new to this i have to apologize.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888566/c-sql-export-outofmemory-issue

Answer (score 5):

You can run the date strings through a method like this:

```
private static string ReformatDate(string input)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "|yyyyMMdd|", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   
}
```

Example:

```
Console.WriteLine(ReformatDate("|20070222|")); // prints 02/22/2007
```

**Update**
Complete sample including file parsing:

```
private const int DATE_COLUMN = 4;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputFile = @"c:\temp\input.txt";
    string outputFile = @"c:\temp\output.txt";
    using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(inputFile))
    using(Stream outputStream = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
    {
        do
        {
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (line == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            writer.WriteLine(TransformLine(line));
        } while (true);
    }

    File.Delete(inputFile);
    File.Move(outputFile, inputFile);
}
private static char[] separator = "|".ToCharArray();
private static string TransformLine(string line)
{
    string[] columns = line.Split(separator);
    columns[DATE_COLUMN] = ReformatDate(columns[4]);
    return string.Join("|", columns);
}

private static string ReformatDate(string input)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Now it will have replaced the original file with one that has the transformed lines.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this a delimited file with multiple delimiters

Comment: Well i could say that this column will always be column #5 (which in this case it would be).  But i would love to have more flexability no matter where i palce it but this column will always have the header of DDate

Comment: You can just make them non-static and internal or public as needed.

Comment: Almost.  for some strange reason it delimites the wrong thing:
input:  386131|386134|386131|386149|20070222  
output: 386131|386134|86/13/07531|86/14/07539|20070222  
20070222 is the date column

Comment: @Mike: I tried to run my code with the input from your comment. It outputs `386131|386134|386131|386149|02/22/2007`. Verify that you invoke `ReformatDate` only on the expected column.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I wouldn't really try anything clever here, the problem is pretty straight forward.

The easiest way to do the conversion is to convert the original to a C# DateTime, and then format it again with the new style. You can use DateTime.Parse method with the format string fitting your old style, and follow it with a ToString call with a different format string. 

[DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ey1cdcx8.aspx)

[DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht77y576.aspx)

[DateTimeFormatInfo class -has the custom format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx)

As for the general solution, I think I'd map the columns to a class with some simple properties. If memory is not an issue, then create a list of these objects from file data, format the dates, and write the objects back. I find it easier to do it this way because it's more transparent and easier to debug than complex regex statements and the like, and because it's a little more maintenance friendly.

The class would have properties mapping to columns (think of what an ORM does for a database). You can add different format options for it, and override the ToString method in creative ways, add different validation/formatting/logic rules etc.

The problem goes sort of like this then:

- create a "get next token" function

  grab the required number of tokens that makes up a row

  pass the tokens to the class constructor, add class to list

  do that until there is nothing left in the file

  start a new file, or overwrite the old one

  for each item in the list, call the ToString method and append the result to the file

Then if your formatting rules change, or the file format or whatever, you have a straightforward maintenance path.

Edit: For a looser schema you can use a Dictionary object in a couple of clever ways, something like this:

- Get the series of tokens representing the first row. This is your mapping for column name/type and its number. You can store them in a simple array - meaning that for every line of text that you read you can look up the name - let's say ColumnArray[TokenNumber] will give you the name of the column.

  For every line of text, create a Dictionary, and fill it with a series of values of the form {ColumnArray[TokenNumber], Token}. This represents your row. Add this dictionary to the list of all rows.

  For every item in the list, reformat item["DDate"] to the desired value

  Then write the list back to the file. First output the tokenized ColumnArray - these are your headers. Then For every row dictionary you can run a loop like this:

```
foreach(Dictionary<string, string> row in rowList){
    foreach(string columnName in ColumnArray){
       WriteToken(row[columnNmae]);
    } 
}
```

### Update

I made something that's fairly generic for this purpose. Slow day today I guess :)

```
public class ListFormatter {
    // stores transformation delegates keyed by column name (multiple keys for each column is allowed)
    public List<KeyValuePair<String, Func<String, String>>> Transforms = new List<KeyValuePair<String, Func<String, String>>>();

    // method for tokenizing and writing back - encapsulate file format to some extent
    public Func<String, String[]> GetTokensFromLine { get; set; }
    public Func<IEnumerable<String>, String> GetLineFromTokens { get; set; }

    public String ReservedColumnNameAnyColumn = String.Empty;
    public String ReservedColumnNameWholeLine = "WholeLine";

    public ListFormatter() {
        // by default let's set up for '|' delimited tokens, client can overwrite however
        GetTokensFromLine = s => { return s.Split('|'); };
        GetLineFromTokens = l => {
            var b = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < l.Count(); i++) {
                b.Append((i > 0) ? " | " + l.ElementAt(i) : l.ElementAt(i));
            }
            return b.ToString();
        };
    }

    public void FormatList(StreamReader inStream, StreamWriter outStream) {
        // get the column names
        var columns = GetTokensFromLine(inStream.ReadLine());
        // TODO - validate that every column has a name
        // write he column header to the output
        outStream.WriteLine(GetLineFromTokens(columns));

        // iterate through the stream
        while (true) {
            // get a line of text, run any transforms registered to work on the whole line
            var line = RunTransforms(inStream.ReadLine(), GetRowTransforms());
            if (line == null) break;
            // get the row of tokens TODO - validate for number of tokens
            var tokens = GetTokensFromLine(line);
            // run transforms on the columns
            for (var i = 0; i < tokens.Count(); i++ ) {
                tokens[i] = RunTransforms(tokens[i], GetColumnTransforms(columns[i]));
            }
            // write the new line to the output
            outStream.WriteLine(GetLineFromTokens(tokens));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the transforms associated with a single column value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<Func<String, String>> GetColumnTransforms(string name) {
        return from kv in Transforms where kv.Key == ReservedColumnNameAnyColumn || kv.Key == name select kv.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the transforms associated with the whole row
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<Func<String, String>> GetRowTransforms() {
        return from kv in Transforms where kv.Key == ReservedColumnNameWholeLine select kv.Value;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Runs the transforms on a string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">The item.</param>
    /// <param name="transformList">The transform list.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string RunTransforms(string item, IEnumerable<Func<String, String>> transformList) {
        if (item != null) {
            foreach (var func in transformList) {
                item = func(item);
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
}

// usage example
public void FormatList() {
    var formatter = new ListFormatter();

    // add some rules

    // formats every line of text
    formatter.Transforms.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Func<string, string>>(formatter.ReservedColumnNameWholeLine, s => s.Trim()));
    // format every column entry
    formatter.Transforms.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Func<string, string>>(formatter.ReservedColumnNameAnyColumn, s => s.Trim()));
    // format that date
    formatter.Transforms.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Func<string, string>>("DDate", s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "oldformat", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("newformat")));

    // format
    using (var reader = File.OpenText("infile"))
    using(var outputStream = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("outfile"))) {
        formatter.FormatList(reader, outputStream);
    }
}
```

Allows you to add arbitrary number of rules for a specific column, all columns, and whole line of text. Uses your delimiter characters by default, but can be overridden however. The actual formatter class works on streams, so any buffer and file management stuff is left up to the client.

The idea is to encapsulate the core functionality into something simple and reusable. So, for example, to add you other text replacements you simply add another rule that works on the whole line of text, or every column value separately, whichever fits the situation. The actual rules are separate from the formatting process and can be tested individually. Here is how you could configure your other replacements:

```
formatter.Transforms.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, Func<string, string>>(formatter.ReservedColumnNameWholeLine, s => {
    // Make other replacements.
    s = s.Replace(@"BegAtt|EndAtt", "BegAtt#|EndAtt#");
    s = s.Replace(@"Cc|*RFP", "CC|RFP");
    s = s.Replace(@"<swme> ", string.Empty);
    s = s.Replace(@" </swme>", ";");
    return s;
}));
```