# C# SQL export (OutofMemory issue)

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to bulk export out of a sql table, the code works fine.  Nothign wrong with it at all, the problem resides in exporting 50 columns at 2.7million rows.  Can anybody help me with the OUtofMemory exception.  I know why it's happening because it tried to read it all to memory then write, but i'm not sure how ot break it up to read line by line then write out without taking forever.

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(textBox3.Text);

string tableid = tableid = Regex.Match(contents, @"CoreDBCaseID=(?<id>\d+)").Groups["id"].Value;
string server = server = Regex.Match(contents, @"Server=(?<Server>[^;]+)").Groups["Server"].Value;
string security = security = Regex.Match(contents, "Security=(?<Security>[^;]+)").Groups["Security"].Value;
string database = database = Regex.Match(contents, "Database=(?<Database>[^\r]+)").Groups["Database"].Value;

string[] data = new string[] {
    string.Format("Table={0}", tableid),
    string.Format("Server={0}", server),
    string.Format("Security={0}", security),
    string.Format("Database={0}", database),
};
string sqltable = ("TDS_C" + tableid + "_table");
String cols = String.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<String>().ToArray());
string sql = "select " + cols + " from " + sqltable + " where *;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=" + database + ";Integrated Security=" + security);
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter tabadapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
tabadapter.FillSchema(dataset, SchemaType.Source, sqltable);
tabadapter.Fill(dataset, sqltable);
DataTable tbltarget = dataset.Tables[0];
string output_text =
    tbltarget.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList()
    .Select(col => col.ColumnName)
    .Aggregate((current, next) => current + "|" + next) + "\r\n"
+
    tbltarget.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToList()
    .Select(row => row.ItemArray.Aggregate((current, next) => current.ToString() + "|" + next.ToString().Replace("\n", "")))
    .Cast<string>().Aggregate((current, next) => current + "\r\n" + next);

File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Export.txt);

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't fill a dataset.  Instead, use a data reader, then you can stream that data out as you read it in, meaning a much smaller memory footprint.

You could look into doing async reads from the db and have that trigger an async write to the file.  This would stop each read-write being a fully blocking operation.

---

Simple example:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)){
connection.Open();
using (FileStream strm = new FileStream(filePath)){
using (TextWriter wrt = new TextWriter(strm)){
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while rdr.Read()
{
    wrt.Write(rdr[0].ToString() + "|" + rdr[1].ToString(); // change for your manipulation of the columns
}
}}}
```

Comment: I'd have to see a code example or what you mean.  That statement above took me about 2 days.  Sorry i'm just to new to figure it out.

Comment: ill test it out shortly and ill let you know!

Comment: it doesnt like this part  

using (TextWriter wrt = new TextWriter(strm)){

Answer (score 1):

THis is something best done by SSIS (if you are using SQL Server). Then call the SSIS package from the code. You shouldn't be moving that amount of data from your database server to your application server to process. Creating a large export file is best done from the database only.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing selects of 10k rows at a time?  Then writing between them.  Kind of a hybrid of the two options you give.

Comment: This implies that he continues to use memory intensive data sets, which are really the wrong tool for exporting data.